# Cos(90) returning a value very close to 0, but I need 0?

Tags: c++

The values for temp_x_btm_left = 0 & temp_y_btm_left=1;

```
angle = 90;

//Moving the bottom left coordinates
_btm_left.real() = (temp_x_btm_left * cos(angle*PI/180)) 
                   - (temp_y_btm_left * sin(angle*PI/180));
_btm_left.imag() = (temp_x_btm_left * sin(angle*PI/180)) 
                   + (temp_y_btm_left * cos(angle*PI/180));
```

The code is supposed to rotate the object 90 degrees counter-clockwise, which it does but the `_btm_left.imag()` returns a value really close to 0 = 1.437949e-009, and I really need it being 0.

I've tried `setprecision()` and `setw()` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Are there any methods for anything like this or do I need to create my own to solve this?!

Comment: `setprecision` and `setw` have to do with streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as |v1-v2| < predefinedDelta, simply consider v1 == v2.

Answer (score 5):

The "magical epsilon" referred to in previous answers is actually provided by the language via

```
 #include <limits>
 std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();
```

and

```
 std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
```

which is "the difference between 1 and the least value greater than 1 that is representable"

Answer (score 4):

The trigonometric functions take an argument in radians, not in degree. Your calculation of `angle*PI/180` doesn't yield exactly PI/2, which is of course not exactly representable as a floating point.

A solution would be a comparison to special values before the conversion to radians, e. g.

```
if (angle == 90.0)
    x = 0.0
else
    x = cos(angle*PI/180.0)
```

Comment: floating-point equal-comparison is not portable and should be avoided (except with zero).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to set up an `Epsilon` equal to some magical small value and then check whether the absolute value of your result provided by a function is less (or less-or-equal) to your `Epsilon`.

(Naming it `Epsilon` is just a convention; it could be `double MagicalNumberIndeed = VerySmallValue;`)

Answer (score 0):

Pre-calculate your angle calculations, then use the results. Something like:

```
if (angle == 90) {
  cos_angle = 0
} else {
  cos_angle = cos(angle)
}
...
_btm_left.real() = ... * cos_angle ...
```

This has the additional benefit of doing fewer calls to `cos()` and `sin()`.

Keep in mind that if `angle` is a float, doing something like `angle == 90` could always return false, because of how floating point numbers are represented internally. You might want to change that to something like:

```
if (abs(angle-90) < some_small_number) {
```