# qSin and qCos wrong result from

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use qSin and qCos but i get wrong values.
Here a simple try

```
for (float angle = 0 ; angle <= 360 ; angle += 90)
    qDebug() << angle << qSin(qDegreesToRadians(angle)) << qCos(qDegreesToRadians(angle));
```

with his output

```
0 0 1
90 1 -4.37114e-08
180 -8.74228e-08 -1
270 -1 1.19249e-08
360 1.74846e-07 1
```

why i can't get 0 where it must be?

Comment: Can you paste the complete code

Comment: 90 is only a nice value to human eyes, computers need to use PI and that has not a nice value to either humans or binary processors.  Looks like you are compiling with -qreal float given the round-off error, use double to get a more precise result.

Comment: @hashdefine i need to calculate sin and cos to place graohical object in a circumference

Comment: @Hans Passant tried also in radiant but nothing change, and tried with double too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not Qt specific, but a general problem of computer's inability to represent floating point numbers with arbitrary precision. See e.g. [Cos(90) returning a value very close to 0, but I need 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219434/cos90-returning-a-value-very-close-to-0-but-i-need-0)

Comment: thanks everybody for the answer, i used the delta solution so if the result is near 0 i change in 0